# KDB string concatenation with symbol list for dynamic query

Tags: select, kdb, q-lang

In this [link](http://www.thalesians.com/finance/index.php/Knowledge_Base/Databases/Kdb#String_concatenation), there is an example on how to include a dynamic parameter. `d`, in a KDB select query:

```
h: hopen`:myhost01:8012 // open connection
d: 2016.02.15 // define date var
symList: `GBPUSD`EURUSD
h raze "select from MarketDepth where date=", string d, ", sym in `GBPUSD`EURUSD" // run query with parameter d
```

Here `d` is of type `date` and is easy to string concatenate in order to generate a dynamic query.

If I want to add `symList` as a dynamic parameter as well by converting to string:

```
raze "select from MarketDepth where date=", string d, ", sym in ", string symList
```

The concatenated string becomes: `select from MarketDepth where date=2016.02.15, sym in GBPUSDEURUSD`, in other words the string concatenation loses the backticks so the query does not run. How can I solve this?

p.S: I know about [functional querying](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/functional-queries-dynamic-sql) but after failing for 2 hours, I have given up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `string SYMBOL` does not preserve a backtick character, so you'll have to append it yourself like this:

```
symList: `GBPUSD`EURUSD
strSymList: "`",'string symList / ("`GBPUSD";"`EURUSD")
```

I used join `,` with [each-both adverb](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#672-each-both) `'` to join a backtick with *each* element of a list. Having your symbol list stringified your dynamic query becomes

```
"select from MarketDepth where date=", (string d), ", sym in ",raze"`",'string symList
```

You can also use `parse` to see how a shape of a functional form of your query will look like.

```
q) parse "select from MarketDepth where date=", (string d), ", sym in ",raze"`",'string symList
(?;`MarketDepth;enlist ((=;`date;2016.02.15);(in;`sym;enlist `GBPUSD`EURUSD));0b;())
```

Now it's easy to create a functional select:

```
?[`MarketDepth;enlist ((=;`date;2016.02.15);(in;`sym;enlist symList));0b;()]
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**: @Ryan Hamilton's solution is probably the best in your particular scenario. You can even make a table name an argument if you want:

```
h({[t;d;s]select from t where date=d,sym in s};`MarketDepth; d; symList)
```

But it is worth noting that you can't use this technique when you need to make a list of columns dynamic. The following will **NOT** work:

```
h({[c;d;s]select c from t where date=d,sym in s};`time`sym; d; symList)
```

You will have to either build a dynamic select expression like you do or use functional  forms.

Comment: Thank you, I spent hours on the functional select as that seems the proper way to do it. However, the parsed tree throws error when I try to run the query. I managed to run it for simpler tables but when one of the where conditioned columns is of type symbol, it somehow doesn't work..

Comment: @Zhubarb: does a functional select I shown not work?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but this one I failed to get to work. Table: `t:([] col1:8?`a`b; col2:til 8; col3:8?9.)`. And when I parse this: `select from t where col1=`a, col2<4`, I get `?[`t;enlist ((=;`col1;enlist `a);(<;`col2;4));0b;()]`, which doesn't give the expected result (i.e. gives a row where col1 is b).  (Sorry the backticks mess the formatting up)

Comment: I see. `enlist` in the constraint is what causing the problem. I don't know why `parse` generates it. A proper functional form is this: ```?[`t;((=;`col1;enlist `a);(<;`col2;4));0b;()]```

Comment: Yes, thank you! When I removed the outer enlist for the where conditions, it worked. It is very unhelpful that when I `parse` the query string, it creates it with the outer enlist though.

Comment: Sorry, just a final question: I tried the each-both adverb solution above to the case where `symList` has a single element, i.e. `symList: *backtick*GBPUSD`, and realised it fails. Can I get it working for `symList` with single and multiple symbols using a generic line?

Comment: `symList` must be a list even when it has just a single element, i.e. ```symList: enlist `GBPUSD```.

Answer (score 7):

No need for functional selects.

```
q)MarketDepth:([] date:9#2016.02.15; sym:9#`A`B)
q)d:2016.02.15
q)symList:`B

q)h ({[dt;sl] select from MarketDepth where date=dt,sym in sl};  d; symList)
date       sym
--------------
2016.02.15 B
2016.02.15 B
2016.02.15 B
2016.02.15 B
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given good alternative approaches for your problem.  But in  case if you need to join string and symbols (or other data types) without losing backtick, function **.Q.s1** does the task.

```
q) .Q.s1 `a`b
q)"`a`b"
q)"select from table where sym in ",.Q.s1 symlist
```

Note: Generally it is not suggested to use `.Q` namespace functions.